# why do I see different values of array size in main vs other function

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion, pass-by-value

I created an array of ten integers and print its size
1. in main
2. in a function named print

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print(int *a)
{
    cout<<sizeof(a);
}
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;
    print(arr);
}
```

The output is :

> 40
>
> 8

I was expecting 40 in both cases (as size of 1 integer=4 times 10 ) but the second case shows size of a single pointer and not the whole array. What's happening here?

Comment: `sizeof(a)` is `sizeof(int*)` which is always constant

Comment: @UnholySheep how does the same thing in main produces 40, there too I should have had size of sizeof(a) as sizeof(int*)

Comment: Arrays can decay to pointers but they aren't pointers.

Comment: @BessieTheCow  after so many days, now I understood what you meant. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the function declaration

```
void print(int *a)
{
    cout<<sizeof(a);
}
```

the function deals with a pointer. So this statement

```
cout<<sizeof(a);
```

outputs the size of the pointer that is equal either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the used system.

Pay attention to that even if you will declare the function like

```
void print(int a[])
{
    cout<<sizeof(a);
}
```

you will get the same result because the parameter is implicitly adjusted by the compiler to the type int *.

That is the previous and this function declarations are equivalent.

If you want that the function would deal with the original array instead of a pointer that points to the first element of the passed array as an argument then declare the function at least like.

```
void print( int ( &a )[10] )
{
    cout<<sizeof(a);
}
```

That is declare the parameter as a reference.

Or you can make the function a template function like

```
template <size_t N>
void print( int ( &a )[N] )
{
    cout<<sizeof(a);
}
```

As the passed array is not being changed in the function then the parameter should have the qualifier const

```
template <size_t N>
void print( const int ( &a )[N] )
{
    cout<<sizeof(a);
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
void print( const int ( &a )[N] )
{
    std::cout << sizeof( a ) << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    int arr[10];

    std::cout << sizeof( arr ) << '\n';

    print( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
40
40
```

Or you could define the template function with a type template parameter. But again the function parameter has a referenced type.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void print( const T &a )
{
    std::cout << sizeof( a ) << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    int arr[10];

    std::cout << sizeof( arr ) << '\n';

    print( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to a function, it gets adjusted into a pointer to its first element inside the function.

So what you see in `print` function isn't the size of the array but the size of the pointer i.e. `sizeof(a)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int*)`.

Answer (score -1):

you should see the output for this code, and observe the difference:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* h()
{
    int *a[10];
    cout<<sizeof(a);
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    int *a=h();
    cout<<sizeof(a);
}
```

Output :

> 40
>
> 8

now main shows size as 8 (size of pointer) and function print shows size of array as 40.

Comment: This program is ill-formed, `return a;` should generate an error